# I want to edit specific item name in my inventory through accessing certain index, my problem is here

Tags: java, arrays

I want to edit the item name by accessing a certain index, but my problem is when I try to edit the name of index 2
index 1 is editing not index 2
here is my output

```java
if (choice2 == 1) {
    System.out.print("Enter Item name: ");
    String itm = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Item unit: ");
    int unit = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Item quantity: ");
    int qty = scan.nextInt();
    item.add(new Materials(itm, unit, qty));
    System.out.println(itm + " " + unit + " " + qty + " Successfully added!");
    // edit item name
} else if (choice2 == 2) {
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println("Edit Materials ");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.print("Enter Item index: ");
    int item_index = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter new name of the item: ");
    String newitem = scan.next();
    for (Materials m : item) {
        m.setItem_name(newitem);
        System.out.println("Item  ->" + m.getItem_name() + " Successfully updated! ");
        break;
    }// view all item in inventory
```

I want to edit name of the indexes.
here is the output

```
 (1) ADD MATERIALS
 (2) EDIT MATERIALS
 (3) VIEW MATERIAL
 (4) Exit
Enter your choice: 3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unique_Id   Item_name       Unit        Quantity
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1:      fish            2       312
2:      cangoods            3       123

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 (1) ADD MATERIALS
 (2) EDIT MATERIALS
 (3) VIEW MATERIAL
 (4) Exit
Enter your choice: 2
----------------------
Edit Materials 
----------------------
Enter Item index: 2
Enter new name of the item: python
Item  ->python Successfully updated! 

 (1) ADD MATERIALS
 (2) EDIT MATERIALS
 (3) VIEW MATERIAL
 (4) Exit
Enter your choice: 3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unique_Id   Item_name       Unit        Quantity
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1:      python          2       312
2:      cangoods            3       123

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 (1) ADD MATERIALS
 (2) EDIT MATERIALS
 (3) VIEW MATERIAL
 (4) Exit
Enter your choice:
```

Comment: Can you explain whats happening and what you expect what happens and how / where that relates to the code you show? What is a "name of an index"? Also please post text output as text instead of as image, a code block should work fine for that

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.com.

There is a small problem in the edit material for loop. You are always editing the first material and breaking the loop. You have to first find the Material object from the list and then update the same.

Check the sample below:

```
if (choice2 == 1) {
  System.out.print("Enter Item name: ");
  String itm = scan.next();
  System.out.print("Enter Item unit: ");
  int unit = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter Item quantity: ");
  int qty = scan.nextInt();
  item.add(new Materials(itm, unit, qty));
  System.out.println(itm + " " + unit + " " + qty + " Successfully added!");
  // edit item name
} else if (choice2 == 2) {
  System.out.println("----------------------");
  System.out.println("Edit Materials ");
  System.out.println("----------------------");
  System.out.print("Enter Item index: ");
  int item_index = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.print("Enter new name of the item: ");
  String newitem = scan.next();
  for (Materials m : item) {
    if (m.getItem_index() == item_index) {
        m.setItem_name(newitem);
        System.out.println("Item  ->" + m.getItem_name() + " Successfully updated! ");
        break;
    }
  }// view all item in inventory
}
```

The difference is in for loop

```
if (m.getItem_index() == item_index) {
  m.setItem_name(newitem);
  System.out.println("Item  ->" + m.getItem_name() + " Successfully updated! ");
  break;
}
```

Since the definition of Materials class was not provided, so there might be a need of correcting the method call `m.getItem_index()` in above code.

Comment: my index no. is auto increment when you add item to arraylist

Comment: Its ok, if the index is set to increment automatically. There will be a variable (where index is set) in Materials class which will be holding/storing index value. You have to use the getter of that method for comparison in if condition. Hope it helps.